# How to get the Class or Type of a button (JButton) in java from its Action Listener?

Tags: java, swing, awt, paintcomponent

```
private class MyCustomButton extends JButton{...}
private class MyCustomButton2 extends MyCustomButton{...}

public class Example1 extends JPanel{
  Example1{
    MyCustomButton b1=new MyCustomButton("0");
    MyCustomButton2 b2=new MyCustomButton1("b2");
  }
  private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener//, KeyListener
  {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
       System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

In the example above I have 2 JButton, one a custom, and the second extends the first.

```
java.awt.event.ActionEvent[ACTION_PERFORMED,cmd=0,when=1395217216471,modifiers=Button1] on **Example1.MyCustomButton**[,165,0,55x55,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@8a13863,flags=16777504,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=pressed.png,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=0,defaultCapable=true]
```

To implement my action listener, I know from the printout java is capable of returning the class of the button I pressed, how do I do that?

Edit 1: 
My goal is to implement a gui that has 2 classes of button, if one is clicked I have a set of actions for that type of button, vice versa, with the hope it will simplify my action listener implementation.

Comment: You should consider making use of the [actions API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), relying on the class type is erronous...

Comment: unrelated: don't extend any of JSomething, they are designed for usage as-are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActionEvent` provides a reference to the `source` that triggered the event, in you case this would the `JButton`.

You could simply check which button triggered the event by comparing the source with a known reference, but it would be simpler to utilise the buttons `actionCommand` properties...

```
if ("name of action".equals(source.getActionCommand())) {...
```

This assumes that you set the buttons `actionCommand` property.

Failing that, your down to the text...

```
JButton btn = (JButton)e.getSource();
if ("0".equals(btn.getText()) {...
```

Personally, that's just asking for trouble, as you might have multiple buttons with the same name.  Better to use the buttons `actionCommand` property.

A better solution would be to just use the [actions API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), which is self contained concept of an action which carries with it configuration information, then you don't care...

Answer (score 1):

`e.getSource().getClass().getName()` returns the full name of the class of the button.

But why do you want it?

Answer (score 0):

use `getSource()` method of `ActionEvent` in `actionPerformed()`:

```
if(e.getSource() instanceof MyCustomButton ){

} else if(e.getSource() instanceof MyCustomButton1 ){

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
if(e.getSource().getClass()==MyCustomButton.class)
```

to make it more robust in place of

```
if(e.getSource().getClass().getName.equals("com.x.y.z.MyCustomButton"))
```

Advantage:

- if in future you change the package of class `MyCustomButton` then also it will work fine.
- change in package is caught at compile time